# Персонаж не идёт за мышью в UNITY 2017

Tags: unity3d

Это код MouseOrbit.js

Проблема в том что игрок от третьего лица не бегает за мышью куда мышь я поворачиваю, должно получиться типа MAX PAYNE управление персонажем, если кто сможет помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо, и ещё я новичок в UNITY использую UNITY 2017

```
var target : Transform;
var distance = 10.0;
var min_distance = 3.0;
var max_distance = 15.0;

var xSpeed = 250.0;
var ySpeed = 120.0;

var yMinLimit = -20;
var yMaxLimit = 80;

private var x = 0.0;
private var y = 0.0;

@AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Orbit")
partial class MouseOrbit { }

function Start () {
    var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    x = angles.y;
    y = angles.x;

    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (GetComponent.<Rigidbody>())
            GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
}

function LateUpdate () {
    if (target) {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(1)){
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02;
                }
                y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")){
            distance=distance-Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")*5;
            if (distance < min_distance) {distance=min_distance;}
            if (distance > max_distance) {distance=max_distance;}
            }

    var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
    var position = rotation * Vector3(0.0, 0.0, -distance) + target.position;

    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
}
}

static function ClampAngle (angle : float, min : float, max : float) {
        if (angle < -360)
                angle += 360;
        if (angle > 360)
                angle -= 360;
        return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
}
```

Comment: `Проблема в том что игрок от третьего лица не бегает за мышью куда мышь я поворачиваю` - а куда бегает сейчас?

Comment: я поворачиваю мышь, а он бегает с помощью клавишь WASD совершенно не реагируя на направление мышки  и куда показывает камера

Comment: там ещё у меня в игре клавиши WASD плохо слушаются команд персонаж просто прибегает к какой нибудь стене и потом плохо слушается команд что делать подскажите персонаж от третьего лица, нет но он конечно бегает но это надо постараться плохое управление с клавиатуры, работаю на UNITY 2017.1